# Generic way of introducing a new variable to every method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, coding-style

```java
public interface Names{
    public List<String> getFirstNames();
    public List<String> getNamesWithPrefix(String prefix);
    public List<String> deleteName(String name);
    ....
    ....
}
```

Now for example, there is a new variable introduced named **String source** which is required to be passed in every method.
Imagine variable source tells from which source i have to fetch Names.

Is there a generic way of defining the source so that these methods should work accordingly?

Option1: Add **String source** to every method and then fetch the source details inside the method which according to me is not a clean code.

Comment: You can add a default method getSource() which returns the correct source, and call that from within the methods that need to. You're also free to override the default method in concrete implementations

Answer (score 0):

you can use ... to have unlimited number of parameters of the same type and in your implementation you control the logic based on the index of your passed parameter

```
public interface Names{
    public List<String> getFirstNames(Strings ... inputs);
    public List<String> getNamesWithPrefix(String ...inputs);
    public List<String> deleteName(String ...inputs );
    ....
    ....
}
```

Although I would not recommend this approach (have generic way of sending parameters) since the usage of your methods (which should be only exposed by your interface) will be coupled to implementation, if you check any Common library you will see method overloading with different parameters used which makes more since for readablity and abstraction of implementation

Comment: I am aware of ... but as you can see, the methods depends on variable Source. Is there any way of building up the source so that methods should work in that source only?
And for overloading too, i've to create methods with variable source for each copy

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem of `dependency injection`. One solution that I can think of is  that, in the implementing class, have a parameterized constructor where you can pass the `source` and then you can use that `source` object in concrete implementation of the interface methods.

Now, since you are just passing the `source` object to the constructor, you can define it in any way you want and your code will still work. In short, your methods will no longer depend on how you define the `source` object.

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the method signatures use `inheritance` to implement a single class for each `source` you have. In this case you can inject the corresponding subclass matching your source. With your Names `interface` and e.g. `source` X and Y it will lead to:

```
public class XNames{
    public List<String> getFirstNames(){...};
    public List<String> getNamesWithPrefix(String prefix){...};
    public List<String> deleteName(String name){...};
    ....
    ....
}


public class YNames{
    public List<String> getFirstNames(){...};
    public List<String> getNamesWithPrefix(String prefix){...};
    public List<String> deleteName(String name){...};
    ....
    ....
}
```